# How do I execute a js render of a modal in a .js.erb file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `main.js.erb` that looks like this:

```
$(document).on("page:change", function(){
  MainJS.init();
    $("#add-video-step-1").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'videos/upload_video') %>");
    $('#myModalLabel').modal(show);
    Ladda.bind('#video-submit');
    console.log("Upload.js.erb has been executed");

});
```

Basically what I want to happen is whenever a button with the id `#video-submit` is pressed, I want it to execute the modal that is in the partial `videos/upload_video`.

Just doing a regular `render 'videos/upload_video'` I think should suffice, but when I try this I get this error:

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `render' for #<#<Class:0x007f916fcf1310>:0x007f91721a9c20>
  (in /app/assets/javascripts/main.js.erb)
```

At this line:

```
$("#myVCModal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'videos/upload_video') %>");
```

Thoughts?

**Edit 1**

Here is the code of the partial, per uDAY's request - i.e. `video/_upload_video.html.erb`:

```
<div class="bootstrap-styles">
 <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Upload your Video</h3>
    <p><i>Step 2 of 2 - TEST</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form">
      <%= form_tag @upload_info[:url], :multipart => true do %>
        <div>Step 2 of 2</div>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :token, @upload_info[:token] %>
        <%= file_field_tag :file, title: 'Choose video to upload' %>
        <p class="uploader">
          <button class="btn btn-success ladda-button" data-color="green" data-style="expand-left"><span class="ladda-label">Upload Video</span><span class="ladda-spinner"></span></button>
        </p>
      <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The underlying question is why did you put `main.js.erb` into assets? The `ERB` templates are not part of assets in any manner and should never be used there. I just don't get the idea behind it. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Well I started off as just `main.js`. The issue I then faced was that I needed to be able to render these JS modals, so that's why I started with this. Alas, here we are.

Comment: There are two approaches dealing with modals. One is to embed modals into ERB view and then just show it via `$('#myModalLabel').modal(show);`. Another is to load modal dynamically from within given action. In this case `get :action as HTML` should load dialog and `put/patch :action as JS/JSON` should persist data it provides. Which approach should be used and when? It depends on the use case. Heavily used modal might be served to the user with view, the others might be loaded on demand.

Comment: @blelump Either way works fine for me. I just want it to work. Can you provide an answer with a complete use-case and I will take it from there. Thanks!

Comment: @marcamillion, do you have code of the partial?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting error because `render` is a method of `views (ActionView)` and you are trying it in assets where it is not available. So to make it work what we should do is initialise `ActionView` and for that your `main.js.erb` should be like:

```
$(document).on("page:change", function(){
  MainJS.init();
    <% action_view = ActionView::Base.new(Rails.configuration.paths["app/views"].first) %>
    $("#add-video-step-1").html("<%= action_view.escape_javascript(action_view.render 'videos/upload_video') %>");
    $('#myModalLabel').modal(show);
    Ladda.bind('#video-submit');
    console.log("Upload.js.erb has been executed");

});
```

I just tried it and it worked for me, give it a try and know if it works for you or not :)

---

For ajax request and render partial thing you can simply send an ajax request to a `controller` `action`put the following code in the corresponding view file (`action.js.erb`):

```
$("#add-video-step-1").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'videos/upload_video') %>");
$('#myModalLabel').modal(show);
```

Comment: This feels like a hacky approach. Is there a more standard Rails way to do this?

Comment: Well this is hacky. The standard way would be either you can make an ajax request to an action and then render this partial & code or you can render this code on the pages where you want it and make it invisible (hide) and then when the button/link is clicked you can show it. Let me know what suits you, I can modify the answer accordingly

Comment: I prefer the ajax request and render that partial and code.

Comment: there is no standard Rails way to execute ActionView's specific method within assets pipeline runtime. So instead '$("#add-video-step-1").html..' stuff you should send ajax request like '$.get( "/action")' responding with modal code. Just like Manoj2411 says... voted up :)

Comment: @ValeryKvon I guess what I really meant to ask was, is there a more standard Rails way to approach what I am approaching. Not necessarily to execute ActionView's specific method within assets pipeline runtime.